# Bash. Passing a variable containing spaces

Tags: bash, whitespace, fontconfig

I am using dmenu list selection tool on linux. Let's assume my typical invocation goes like that:

```
ls | dmenu $DMENU_OPTIONS
```

Settings from .dmenurc:

```
DMENU_FN="Liberation:size=16"
DMENU_OPTIONS="<...> -fn $DMENU_FN"
```

Then, I have use some quicklaunch script based on dmenu. It takes dmenu options with this line:

```
dmenu_cmd="dmenu $DMENU_OPTIONS"
```

Now, I switch font name to **Liberation Mono** and the font piece is now recognised as two parameters for one option. Dmenu gets syntax error. I couldn't get around that using quotes or backslashes.
So there is a variable with a spacebar which should be passed to another variable.

Comment: Depending on how many dereferences there are, you might need a lot of consecutive backslashes. How many did you try? Did you put quotes around the top level pass of `ls | dmenu "$DMENU_OPTIONS" | wc`?

Comment: If I put backslash before that whitespace it doesn't do any job, i.e. the two chars are passed as is.  How I check it: edit rc file => $ . .dmenurc && ls | dmenu $DMENU_OPTIONS => get error => $ echo $DMENU_OPTIONS => see chars remain as-is

Comment: Quotes on "$DMENU_OPTIONS" don't help. I hope some stuff with brackets or a function would do the trick..

Comment: Whatever backslashes/quotes I put the `$DMENU_OPTIONS` and check with `echo` , `dmenu "$DMENU_OPTIONS"` fails to eat that whitespace while same inline `dmenu -fn "Liberation Mono"` and `dmenu -fn Liberation\ Mono` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you split font name from other arguments like the example below and use double quotes, it will work:

```
DMENU_FONT="Dejavu Sans Mono:medium:size=18"
DMENU_OPTS="-nb #191919 -nf #FF0000 -sb #FF9318 -sf #191919"
ls | dmenu -fn "$DMENU_FONT" $DMENU_OPTS
```

Notice that `DMENU_FONT` is within double quotes while `DMENU_OPTS` is not, as the goal is returning font name as a single value, and the second variable as multiple arguments.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I used for this is to create LiberMono alias for Liberation Mono font using fontconfig. Just add such file:

> ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

```
<!-- Insert joke here -->
<match>
  <test name="family"><string>LiberMono</string></test>
  <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
    <string>Liberation Mono</string>
  </edit>
</match>
```